# plain TeX theory, \afterassignment

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

Is there a real difference between

```
\newcount\acounter
\def\dosomething{\afterassignment\dosomesecret\acounter=}
\def\dosomesecret{I do something with \the\acounter}
```

and

```
\newcount\acounter
\def\dosomething#1{\acounter=#1%
    I do something with \the\acounter}
```

What is the *plus* of `\afterassignment`?
Why should I prefer one solution over the other?

Answer (score 34):

The main difference is that using `\afterassignment` you can preserve the assignment syntax.
So in your counter example any number of tokens following `\dosomething` would be expanded until a sequence of non expandable tokens making a `<number>` are scanned.  The second version forces a macro-argument syntax where the number has to be given as a single token or brace group. Which is preferable depends on what you are trying to do.

Another example from the latex sources

```
\def\protected@edef{%
   \let\@@protect\protect
   \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
   \afterassignment\restore@protect
   \edef
}
```

`\protected@edef` takes the syntax of `\edef` with delimited arguments etc and restores the meaning of `\protect` after the `\edef`. So you can do

```
\protectected@edef\foo#1#2\@nil{.....#1...#2}
```

It would be rather less convenient to do that without using `\afterassignment`.

Another, perhaps better, example again based on usage in the latex base, the following plain TeX file

```
\def\removetonil#1\xx{}

\def\myset#1{\afterassignment\removetonil
             \dimen0=#1pt\relax\xx
             \immediate\write20{[\the\dimen0]}}

\myset{3}
\myset{3em}    
\myset{3cm}
\myset{\vsize}

\bye
```

Produces

```
[3.0pt]
[30.00005pt]
[85.35826pt]
[643.20255pt]
```

This is setting `\dimen0` to a user-specified length where the argument may omit the units (defaulting to `pt`) or give explicit units, or be a TeX dimen register or primitive such as `\vsize`.  By using `\afterassignment` the primitive assignment may or may not use  tokens after `#1` `pt\relax` will be used if the argument is a `<number>` but not if it is already a dimension. Because `\removetonil` is inserted immediately after the assignment it can clear away any unused tokens.

Answer (score 11):

The `\afterassignment` macro exposes TeX's lexing routines to the user. As David pointed it out in his answer, this can simplify the processing of macro arguments.  You can also build on this to elaborate lexers or parsers in plain TeX.

I wrote the geoptk package for plain TeX, which allows to define macros taking arguments as TeX primitives `\hbox`, `\hfill` and so on do. Using this package, you can define a macro `\begindisplay` that you can call like

```
\begindisplay file {chapter1} literal offset 20pt
```

This input text is replaced by

```
\display@M{%
    \getoptk@behaviour@display@file{chapter1}%
    \getoptk@behaviour@display@literal
    \getoptk@behaviour@display@dimen{20pt}%
}
```

so that `\display@M` can do its job and trigger the behaviours at the appropriate time.

The lexing routine involved heavily relies on `\afterassignment`.  The package code is short enough, so that you can “get it” in a couple of hours and I also wrote an article in TUGBoat about this.

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/getoptk

http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/

Comment: in the example, can one switch the order of things after `\begindisplay`: `\begindisplay offset 20pt file {chapter1}`?

Comment: Of course you can! :-)

Comment: ... great :) (@zuié to make it 15 characters)

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald: I just had a quick look at your package. There seems to be a typo in the documentation: you use 'dimen' where you mean 'offset'. This also carried over to your answer. :-)

Comment: @mhelvens I admit, I copy and edited the example from the documentation of the package. :)  I will fix this, thank you for pointing it out!