# Test whether passed parameter is a number (possibly floating point) or dimension

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

With Ti*k*Z using the `calc` library you can write things along the lines of

```
\node (A) at ($(0,0)!0.75!(1,1)$) {};
```

or you can write something (rather different)

```
\node (B) at ($(0,0)!2in!(1,1)$) {};
```

What I would like to do is create a command that takes an argument which is either a scalar or a dimension.

Naively I would like to do something like

```
\def\test#1{\ifdim#1\relax ... \else ... \fi}
```

Of course, that is completely wrong since `\ifdim` compares the values of two dimensions. So, what I really would like is something more like

```
\def\test#1{\ifIsDimension#1\relax ... \else ... \fi}
```

Any suggestions how I go about this?

Comment: Hmm... I think you are trying to answer my deleted question. :-)

Comment: Why don't you let TikZ take care what `#1` is? Or is it just an example?

Comment: @percusse I really just meant the TikZ code to be illustrative of a situation in which a macro is able to discern whether a passed value is a dimension or not and subsequently modify its own behavior.

Comment: @Marienplatz Perhaps then you'd be interested in the answer I came up with after seeing what others had suggested.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you don't mind the overhead of the `pgfmath` parser you can parse the number and check `\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared`. This is true if a TeX unit is specified *at any point* in the expression, or if the expression contains something that TeX regards has having units, such as skip, and box dimensions.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\parindent0pt

\def\print#1{\expandafter\Print#1@}
\def\Print#1{\if#1@\else\string#1\relax\expandafter\Print\fi}

\begin{document}

\newcount\mycount
\newdimen\mydimen
\newskip\myskip
\mycount=1
\mydimen=1pt
\myskip=1pt plus 1pt
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{1}

\begin{minipage}{3in}
\foreach \value in {1, 1.0, 1e0, sin(1), 1cm, 1pt, 1mm, 1sp, 1mu, sin(1pt), 1+1pt,
    \mycount, \mydimen, \myskip, \wd\mybox, \mycount+1pt, width("1")}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\value}
    Expression \hbox to 2.5cm{\hfill`{\tt\print\value}'}
    \ifpgfmathunitsdeclared
        \emph{\bfseries has} a unit
    \else
        has no units
    \fi

}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's also worth noting that there is a macro `\pgfmathpostparse` which is executed after the parser has finished but just before it exits in which further stuff an be done. Initially it is set to `\relax` but is advisable to check its value in case some library or other package changes it.

The result of the parse will be in `\pgfmathresult` and it is *possible* to change it (if one really wanted to). It is however still inside a TeX group so `\global` must be used if the result of some test is required.

The following example using a crude integer test is not great as the parser rarely returns integers (there are a few exceptions shown below) but illustrates how it can be used.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\parindent0pt

\makeatletter
\newif\ifpgfmathresultinteger
\def\pgfmathpostparse{%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@in@\expandafter.\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@%
        \global\pgfmathresultintegerfalse%
    \else%
        \global\pgfmathresultintegertrue%
    \fi%
}

\def\print#1{\expandafter\Print#1@}
\def\Print#1{\if#1@\else\string#1\relax\expandafter\Print\fi}


\begin{document}

\newcount\mycount
\newdimen\mydimen

\mycount=1
\mydimen=1pt

\begin{minipage}{3.5in}
\foreach \value in {1, int(1.0), \mycount, \mydimen, int(\mydimen+1pt), \mycount+1pt}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\value}
    Parsing \hbox to 3.5cm{\hfill`{\tt\print\value}'} 
    does
    \ifpgfmathresultinteger
    \else
        \emph{\bfseries not} 
    \fi
    give an integer

}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I'll accept this as the answer even though I've developed my own solution.  Your answer got me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: As @Mark said, the problem with this approach to the integer question is, annoyingly enough, `\pgfmathparse{1+1}` sets `\pgfmathresult` to `2.0`. Because of this, your code gives the undesirable result "'1+1' does not give an integer". In fact, there are only two conditions in which it will say the result is an integer: either no math was done, as in `\pgfmathparse{12}`, or the outermost operation was surrounded by `int`, as in `\pgfmathparse{int(1+1)}` but not `\pgfmathparse{int(1+1)+1}`. I wrote a more complicated check that gives true if the result is either `n.0` or `n`, for an integer n.

Answer (score 11):

This is of course slow, but should take care of all the cases (number, dimension, wrong input).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfIsDim}{mmm}
 {
  \aellet_ifisdim:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_aellet_ifisdim_arg_tl
\bool_new:N \l_aellet_ifisdim_has_unit_bool
\regex_const:Nn \c_aellet_unit_regex { (pt|pc|in|bp|cm|mm|dd|cc|sp|em|ex|px)\s*\Z }
\regex_const:Nn \c_aellet_number_regex { \A\s*(\+|\-)*[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\s*\Z }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aellet_ifisdim:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_aellet_ifisdim_arg_tl { #1 }
  \regex_match:NnTF \c_aellet_unit_regex { #1 }
   {% there is a unit of measure at the end
    \bool_set_true:N \l_aellet_ifisdim_has_unit_bool
    \regex_replace_once:NnN \c_aellet_unit_regex { } \l_aellet_ifisdim_arg_tl
   }
   {% no unit of measure
    \bool_set_false:N \l_aellet_ifisdim_has_unit_bool
   }
  \regex_match:NVTF \c_aellet_number_regex \l_aellet_ifisdim_arg_tl
   {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_aellet_ifisdim_has_unit_bool { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \ERROR
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:NnTF { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\IfIsDim{3.5pt}{\typeout{IS DIM}}{\typeout{IS NUMBER}}
\IfIsDim{3.5}{\typeout{IS DIM}}{\typeout{IS NUMBER}}
\IfIsDim{-3}{\typeout{IS DIM}}{\typeout{IS NUMBER}}
\IfIsDim{+--.5}{\typeout{IS DIM}}{\typeout{IS NUMBER}}
\IfIsDim{ .5 }{\typeout{IS DIM}}{\typeout{IS NUMBER}}
\IfIsDim{3.5 in}{\typeout{IS DIM}}{\typeout{IS NUMBER}}
\IfIsDim{3.5pq}{\typeout{IS DIM}}{\typeout{IS NUMBER}}

\stop
```

Here's the output on the terminal

```
IS DIM
IS NUMBER
IS NUMBER
IS NUMBER
IS NUMBER
IS DIM
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ERROR

l.41 ...pq}{\typeout{IS DIM}}{\typeout{IS NUMBER}}

?
```

Comment: The `l3regex` package mentioned in the answer should no longer be loaded, because it has been incorporated in `expl3`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the way how PSTricks sets a length with or without a unit (run with `tex`):

```
\catcode`\@=11
\newdimen\psunit \psunit=10pt% the current unit, can be any value
\def\pstunit@off{\let\@psunit\ignorespaces\ignorespaces}
%
\def\pssetlength#1#2{%  #1: dimen  #2 value (unit)
  \let\@psunit\psunit
  \afterassignment\pstunit@off
  #1 #2\@psunit}

\pssetlength\psunit{2} \the\psunit   %  2 times of the current unit

\pssetlength\psunit{1cm} \the\psunit %  absolute 1cm, the new current unit and so on
\bye
```

It is really simple:

- If `#2` has no unit then the dimen `#1` is set to `#2\@psunit` and
  the `\afterassignment` has no meaning because it is executed *after*
  the length setting.
- If `#2` has a unit then the dimen `#1` is set to `#2` and the following `\@psunit` is like a `\ignorespaces`; it was redefined by `\afterassignment`.

Comment: Basic LaTeX has something similar with `\@defaultunits`.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @MarkWibrow, I've been pointed in the correct direction.

Between Mark Wibrow's answer and the solution posted by @DavidCarlisle regarding [plain TeX theory, \afterassignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65464/22413), I've been able to put together an answer which avoids having to load the entire `pgfmath` library.

Here's what I came up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifaemath@dimen@
\newlength{\ae@dummy@length}
\def\aemath@dimen@#1{%
  \begingroup
    \afterassignment\aemath@dimen@@%
    \ae@dummy@length=#1pt\relax\aemath@}
\def\aemath@dimen@@#1#2\aemath@{%
  \endgroup%%
  \ifx#1\relax%
    \aemath@dimen@false
  \else
    \aemath@dimen@true
  \fi}
\def\ifIsDimension#1#2#3{%%
  \aemath@dimen@{#1}%%
  \ifaemath@dimen@ #2\else #3\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Hello

\ifIsDimension{2cm}{Dimension}{Other}

\ifIsDimension{0.25}{Dimension}{Other}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Essentially, I looked at the code for `\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared` and found that the core of what makes this works lies in the code for the macro `\pgfmath@dimen@`.  After getting a better understanding of what `\afterassignment` does (from David Carlisle's answer mentioned above), I was able to tweak the `pgfmath` code get something working.

Comment: A few comments on your implementation: In `\aemath@dimen@@` it is safer to do `\ifx\relax#1%`, as the only thing failing this test would be if `#1=\relax...`, in your version anything would fail with `#1=<tok><tok>...` (so anything starting with two identical tokens). Also you don't need `\ifaemath@dimen@`, you could as well use `\long\def\aemath@dimen@@#1\aemath@#2#3{\endgroup\ifx\relax#1#3\else#2\fi}` and use `\let\ifIsDimension\aemath@dimen@` instead of your definition of `\ifIsDimension`.

Answer (score 4):

I used A. Ellet's answer, but shortened it to

```
\def\isdimen#1{\afterassignment\isdimen@\tempdimen=#1em\relax}
\def\isdimen@#1\relax{\ifx&#1&\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else \expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi}
```

Also, you can use the same idea to check whether something is an integer:

```
\def\isint#1{\afterassignment\isint@\tempcount=#1\relax}
\def\isint@#1\relax{\ifx&#1&\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
```

Sadly, these aren't expandable.

Also if you want to use the `\pgfmathparse` route to check whether something is an integer, the following expandable macro checks whether the value of `\pgfmathresult` is either of the form `n` or `n.0`.

```
\def\ifpgfmathresultisint{\expandafter\ifpgfmathresultisint@\pgfmathresult..\nil}
\def\ifpgfmathresultisint@#1.#2.#3\nil{%
    \ifx\nil#2\nil
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \ifnum#2=0
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
    \fi
}
```

Comment: you have an extra space token after `&` in `\isdimen@` and `\isint@`.

Comment: I fixed another spurious space; I'd see better `\ifx\hfuzz#2\hfuzz` rather than `\nil`.

Comment: That has the advantage in general that \hfuzz has some other definition, so \ifx\hfuzz\undefinedcommand\hfuzz gives false (doesn't matter in this case though). I usually use \someprefix@nil, and then \def\myprefix@nil{unique expansion text}. It's a nasty surprise when the argument starts with an undefined command and the test passes.

Answer (score 3):

As expandability was mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285295/4686), here is one such expandable test. Read the code comments about what it can or not treat.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Expandable macro to check if some input #1 restricted
% to be composed with
%  signs, optional digits, optional decimal mark, optional digits, one
%  optional ending unit of dimension
% There must be at least one digit.
% 
% returns
%  \z@  if an integer (< 2^30)
%  \@ne if a decimal number (=dimension without unit)
%  \tw@ if a dimension

% badly formed inputs (wrong units etc...) are NOT treated.

% Non explicit things like \ht0 or \count0 do pass through.

% Inputs such as +.5 are annoying as we can't feed them to \numexpr.
% Hence I use \dimexpr, but integers are then limited to be <2^30 rather than
% <2^31.

\makeatletter
\def\checktype #1% returns \z@, \@ne, or \tw@.
   {\romannumeral`\^^@\expandafter\checktype@i\the\numexpr0*\dimexpr#1sp!?{#1}}%
\def\checktype@i 0#1#2?%
   {\ifx!#1\expandafter\checktype@ii\else\expandafter \checktype@isdim\fi}%
\def\checktype@isdim #1{\tw@}%
\def\checktype@ii #1% integer or decimal
   {\expandafter\checktype@iii #1.?!}%
\def\checktype@iii #1.#2#3!%
   {\ifx?#2\expandafter\z@\else\expandafter\@ne\fi}%

\def\TellType #1{\ifcase\checktype{#1}%<- leave no space here
    \texttt{\detokenize{#1}} is \emph{INTEGER}\or 
    \texttt{\detokenize{#1}} is \emph{DECIMAL}\or
    \texttt{\detokenize{#1}} is \emph{DIMENSION}\fi }

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

\TellType{3.5pt}\par
\TellType{3.5}\par
\TellType{-3}\par
\TellType{+--.5}\par
\TellType{ .5 }\par
\TellType{3.5 in}\par
% \TellType{3.5pq} % bad input is not treated
\TellType{-+-++---1278997}\par
\TellType{-+-++---1278.997}\par
\TellType{-+-++---1278.997bp}\par
\TellType{-+-++---1278997.}\par
\TellType{-+-++---.1278997}\par
\TellType{-+-++---.1278997ex}\par
\TellType{\number"3FFFFFFF}\par
% \TellType{\number"40000000}\par % "Dimension too large." error
\TellType{\ht0}\par
\TellType{\count0}\par
\end{document}
```

output

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 2):

**The macros provided here only test whether something is an integer/float or a dimension. Arguments which are neither are not treated and might fail badly.**

I did try some things and the fastest I came up with as of now is the following (non-expandable):

```latex
\newdimen\myifdimen@gobbledimen
\newdimen\myifdimen@end
% if #1 is no dimen, but a number/float it'll be used as a factor of
% \myifdimen@end, resulting in the first \myifdimen@end being removed from the
% input stream as part of the assignment. After the assignment everything till
% the first \myifdimen@end will be gobbled, leaving just \@secondoftwo in the
% number/float case, and \myifdimen@true otherwise.
\protected\long\def\myifdimen#1%
  {%
    \afterassignment\myifdimen@
    % don't remove the space v
    \myifdimen@gobbledimen=#1 \myifdimen@end\myifdimen@true
    \myifdimen@end\@secondoftwo
  }
\long\def\myifdimen@#1\myifdimen@end{}
% just removes the remaining tokens of the test and uses the first of two
% arguments
\long\def\myifdimen@true\myifdimen@end\@secondoftwo#1#2{#1}
```

The fastest expandable version I got so far is:

```latex
\let\myifdimenExp@stop\relax
% \dimexpr will be ended by \myifdimen@end if #1 is a complete dimension. If
% that's not the case \myifdimen@end will be part of the expression, and
% \dimexpr will remove the first \myifdimenExp@stop, as \dimexpr is ended by
% \relax and absorbs it. \myifdimenExp@ will remove anything up to the first
% \myifdimenExp@stop, so if #1 was a dimension \myifdimenExp@true will be used,
% else \@secondoftwo.
\long\def\myifdimenExp#1%
  {%
    % don't remove the space                v
    \expandafter\myifdimenExp@\the\dimexpr#1 \myifdimen@end\myifdimenExp@stop
    \myifdimenExp@true\myifdimenExp@stop\@secondoftwo
  }
% gobble the result of \dimexpr, and possibly \myifdimenExp@true.
\long\def\myifdimenExp@#1\myifdimenExp@stop{}
% removes the remainder of the test and uses the first argument.
\long\def\myifdimenExp@true\myifdimenExp@stop\@secondoftwo#1#2{#1}
```

Both versions work for integers and floats <2^31 and dimensions up to `\maxdimen` (usually `16383.99998pt`).

The expandable version needs about 30% more time than the non-expandable one.

A complete document using both versions:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\myifdimen@gobbledimen
\newdimen\myifdimen@end

\protected\long\def\myifdimen#1%
  {%
    \afterassignment\myifdimen@
    \myifdimen@gobbledimen=#1 \myifdimen@end\myifdimen@true
    \myifdimen@end\@secondoftwo
  }
\long\def\myifdimen@#1\myifdimen@end{}
\long\def\myifdimen@true\myifdimen@end\@secondoftwo#1#2{#1}

\let\myifdimenExp@stop\relax
\long\def\myifdimenExp#1%
  {%
    \expandafter\myifdimenExp@\the\dimexpr#1 \myifdimen@end\myifdimenExp@stop
    \myifdimenExp@true\myifdimenExp@stop\@secondoftwo
  }
\long\def\myifdimenExp@true\myifdimenExp@stop\@secondoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\myifdimenExp@#1\myifdimenExp@stop{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\myifdimen{1}{yes}{no}
\myifdimen{1pt}{yes}{no}

\edef\foo{\myifdimenExp{1}{yes}{no} \myifdimenExp{1pt}{yes}{no}}
\texttt{\meaning\foo}
\end{document}
```