# Looking to distinguish between a scale factor and a dimension

Tags: conditionals, dimensions

I'd like to be able to define a macro, say, `\def\testit{<something>}` and then test to see what `<something>` is. If `<something>` is a dimension (e.g, `4in`) then I can do

```
\resizebox{4in}{<thing to be resized>}
```

otherwise (e.g,. `<something>=0.75`) I'll do

```
\scalebox{0.75}{<thing to be scaled>}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be simpler to store away the information when `\testit` is defined?  In a boolean flag, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The information is being 'stored' in `\testit`. Also unsure what is meant by 'in a boolean flag'.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the documentation of the `ifthen` package: if you have a TeXLive distribution, just open a terminal emulator window and type `texdoc ifthen`.  After that, I suggest reading the documentation of the `xifthen` package, too (`texdoc xifthen`).

Comment: Yes, I know what booleans are and how to use them. Indeed, just to make sure I looked at Carlisle's `ifthen` documentation earlier today. Fortunately I found an answer in A. Ellet's answer to <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138737/test-whether-passed-parameter-is-a-number-possibly-floating-point-or-dimension?rq=1>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to what LaTeX does for `\fontsize`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dimenorfactor}[3]{%
  \afterassignment\dim@or@factor\skip@=#1pt@{#2}{#3}%
}
\def\dim@or@factor#1@#2#3{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax#3\else#2\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newlength{\testdim}\setlength{\testdim}{4pt}
\newcommand\test[1]{%
  \dimenorfactor{#1}{\typeout{#1 is a dimen}}{\typeout{#1 is not a dimen}}%
}

\test{123 }
\test{1.23}
\test{123.22 mm}
\test{-.2 pt }

\stop
```

Output on the terminal:

```
123  is not a dimen
1.23 is not a dimen
123.22 mm is a dimen
-.2 pt  is a dimen
\testdim  is a dimen
```

Comment: I should have made that association myself. Delighted you did. Thank you very much.